# TightVNC connection constantly fails

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I installed TightVNC on my Raspberry Pi and Windows computer, but when I try to start the connection I get an error on my Windows computer that says:

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

The weird part is that the connection used to work fine before but now it has stopped. All other solutions I found on the internet did not seem to work so I thought of posting on here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check following -

- Check if tightvnceserver is running on your RPi.
- Check if you are connecting to the correct port on which tightvncserver is running.
- Make sure you can ping your RPi from windows machine.
- Make sure the ports are not blocked by firewall on windows.